# explanation of DC ceiling fan motor and hum and noise

Tags: dc, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

I asked a while back why does a ~$150 120vac electric ceiling fan, above my bed at home, hum and agitate me.

Didn't come to a 100% solid reason but I believe it's due to that motor being a brushless single phase AC where the windings in the case that surround the rotating armature cause the metal motor case to vibrate as the winding(s) are on/off energized to create a rotating magnetic field.  That force creates a vibration in the thin metal motor case, **more so on the slow motor speed setting**, that can be heard.  Maybe if it were a thicker metal case and the windings were encased in epoxy it would prevent any audible vibration from happening... but i get it,  unrealistic to mass produce such a thing and sell for $100.

I see **DC fan motors** now for ceiling fans being advertised, although such a ceiling fan runs $300+.  Not asking what dc motor ceiling fan i should buy... sort of... but can someone elaborate on the physical and electrical vocabulary and operating principles of such a **multi-speed** DC motor?  I want to have a good understanding to see if I can understand why or why not a vibration may or not be likely with such a motor... expecting them to be mass produced also having a thin metal motor casing.  I believe it's the motor casing that's vibrating when the electric motor is running causing an audible hum, would like to figure out how likely that would be possible in the type of DC motors being used in some ceiling fans now.

Comment: Are worried about vibration or hum? One is more a function of the balance of the blades, the other is caused by motor coils directly, although certainly resonant ringing and lack of insulation of the case contributes to it's audibility. Place your ear to a laptop charger and you will hear whine, that is the SMPS coil singing even though it is encased in plastic.

Comment: my fan on low speed, spinning as slow as it does, the audible hum is not caused by any mass imbalance this i am sure of. and the hum at low speed is terrible. It spins on high speed just fine and is balanced and any hum that is on high speed you cannot hear because of air noise.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions, edit the first question

Comment: dude its not a duplicate question.  is a DC motor not different than an AC motor?

Comment: Consumer products are not really about engineering and multiple questions about similar topics are not good either.

Comment: A speaker is made from a magnet and a coil, so is a motor. Motors are not designed to make noise, but it is a byproduct of sending current through the coil. I suspect that this is due to small gaps in between the windings, which causes the whole winding to expand and contract and cause a small amount of vibrations which are audible.

Comment: AC fans will make an audible hum at 60Hz, DC will be motor commutation hum (a DC fan has to switch DC to AC to make the motor turn)

Comment: @ron, don't ask why the hum agitates you ... if you do not know, then how can anyone else know